# How to create Radio buttons with Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I've not been able to find examples of how to implement Radio buttons in Formik's own documentation or over the internet. I am trying to convert the below to be radio buttons

```
<Form>
  <Field name="prices" as="select">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
  </Field>
</Form>
```

I've tried changing `as` to be `radio` or remove it and use `type` instead, with `radio`, but it also won't work

Answer (score 6):

Create your Input component first:

```
const RadioButton = ({
  field: { name, value, onChange, onBlur },
  id,
  label,
  className,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name={name}
        id={id}
        type="radio"
        value={id} // could be something else for output?
        checked={id === value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        className={classNames('radio-button')}
        {...props}
      />
      <label htmlFor={id}>
        {label}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then create a Radio Group like this, Note the name should be the same:

```
           <Field
              component={RadioButton}
              name="radioGroup"
              id="radioOption1"
              label="Choose this option"
            />
            <Field
              component={RadioButton}
              name="radioGroup"
              id="radioOption2"
              label="Or choose this one"
            />
```

Comment: What is the classNames function?

Comment: classNames is a utility to apply classnames conditionally, in this case it's not really doing anything. You could be apply a style for the radio-button by default and add another css class through the props:

className={classNames(propsClassname,'radio-button')}

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { FieldProps } from 'formik';
import cn from 'classnames';
import get from 'lodash/get';

import './RadioInput.scss';

interface IProps extends FieldProps {
  label?: string,
  disabled?: boolean,
  className?: string,
  id: string,
}

const RadioInput: FC<IProps> = (
  {
    id,
    label = '',
    form: { values, touched, errors },
    field,
    disabled = false,
    className,
  },
) => {
  const currentFormValue = get(values, field.name);

  return (
    <div className={cn(['RadioInput', className])}>
      <input
        checked={currentFormValue === field.value}
        {...field}
        type="radio"
        id={id}
        disabled={disabled}
      />
      <label htmlFor={id}>
        {label}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RadioInput;
```

```css
.RadioInput {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.RadioInput input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.RadioInput label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 0;
  line-height: 18px;
  user-select: none;
}

.RadioInput label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  background: url('./../../assets/img/radio-off.svg') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

/* Checked */
.RadioInput input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
  background: url('./../../assets/img/radio-on.svg') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

/* Hover */
.RadioInput label:hover:before {
  filter: brightness(120%);
}

/* Disabled */
.RadioInput input[type=radio]:disabled + label:before {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```js
<Field
  name="mainCharacter.occupation"
  value="1"
  id="mainCharacter.occupation.1"
  disabled={isSubmitting}
  component={RadioInput}
  label="Primary School"
/>
<Field
  id="mainCharacter.occupation.2"
  name="mainCharacter.occupation"
  value="2"
  disabled={isSubmitting}
  component={RadioInput}
  label="High School"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className='row mb-7'>
                        <label className='col-lg-4 col-form-label required fw-bold fs-6 mb-2'>
                          Shipping Option
                        </label>

                        <div className='col-lg-8 fv-row'>
                          <div className='d-flex align-items-center mt-3'>
                            <label className='form-check form-check-inline form-check-solid me-5'>
                              <input
                                {...formik.getFieldProps('shipping_option')}
                                className={clsx(
                                  'form-check-input  form-control-solid mb-3 mb-lg-0',
                                  {
                                    'is-invalid':
                                      formik.touched.shipping_option &&
                                      formik.errors.shipping_option,
                                  },
                                  {
                                    'is-valid':
                                      formik.touched.shipping_option &&
                                      !formik.errors.shipping_option,
                                  }
                                )}
                                name='shipping_option'
                                type='radio'
                                value={'Seller Delivery'}
                                checked={formik?.values?.shipping_option==="Seller Delivery"}
                                
                              />
                              <span className='fw-bold ps-2 fs-6'>Seller Delivery</span>
                            </label>

                            <label className='form-check form-check-inline form-check-solid'>
                              <input
                                
                                {...formik.getFieldProps('shipping_option')}
                                className={clsx(
                                  'form-check-input  form-control-solid mb-3 mb-lg-0',
                                  {
                                    'is-invalid':
                                      formik.touched.shipping_option &&
                                      formik.errors.shipping_option,
                                  },
                                  {
                                    'is-valid':
                                      formik.touched.shipping_option &&
                                      !formik.errors.shipping_option,
                                  }
                                )}
                                name='shipping_option'
                                type='radio'
                                value={'ekShop Fulfillment'}
                                checked={formik?.values?.shipping_option==="ekShop Fulfillment"}

                                
                              />
                              <span className='fw-bold ps-2 fs-6'>ekShop Fulfillment</span>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          {formik.touched.shipping_option && formik.errors.shipping_option && (
                            <div className='fv-plugins-message-container'>
                              <div className='fv-help-block'>
                                <span role='alert'>
                                  {formik?.errors?.shipping_option as string}{' '}
                                </span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </div>
                      </div>
```